# How to disable logging page

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Every time I do any action Logging Page pop-up.

How Can I disable Logging Page and Statement cards ?

SQL Dev version 4.2.0.16.260 Build 16.260.1303

Comment: must be the most annoying feature ever release by anyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can disable this, but you can hide it but pressing CTRL-SHIFT-L, or deselecting 'Log' on the 'View' menu.

Source: http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/12/sql-developer-4-1-log-all-the-queries/